# Can I call drupal_add_css from a block?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm building an HTML table in a php filter in a block. Can I/is it OK if I call drupal_add_css() from the block php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Although probably ok, rather than using the PHP filter, you may be interested in using

- [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
- [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

To define your blocks instead. Perfectly fine to use [drupal_add_css](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) there.

Eg :

```
<?php
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/css/custom.css', array('group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));
?>
```

Comment: It's bad practice to use the PHP filter, as it messes with backups (can't place code in a repository), maintenance (code is stored in different areas), creates security holes. It's also been removed from D8 core. I would unless, for what ever reason, using the php filter is 100% unavoidable, it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using hook_block_view, which implies creating the block content fully by hooked functions, i am using hook_block_view_alter like this. It maintains the capability to alter the content using Drupal's block admin pages in more user friendly way :

```
function font_awesome_add_css_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if (!is_object($data) && !isset($data->bid)) {
    return;
  } 
  switch ($data->bid) {
    case '366':
      if (is_array($data['content'])) {
        break;
      }
      $current_content = $block['content'];
      $block['content'] = array(
        '#markup' => $current_content,
        '#attached' => array(
          'css' => array(
            'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'
          ),
        ),
      );
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: PS. The drupal_add_css PHP code snippet didn't work for me. "CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));" was shown in my block's final content view